# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null after upgrading to PHP 8.0

Tags: wordpress, fatal-error

One of my older WordPress websites got broken after the hosting company switched to PHP 8.0. I have deactivated all the plugins and switched to WP default theme through FTP and PHPMyadmin, and then I got a few Fatal errors, which I managed to solve, but I got really stuck with this one since I am not a developer.

Browser message:

> Warning: Undefined array key "wp_the_query" in */public_html/wp-settings.php on line 342
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in */public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php:601 Stack trace: #0 */public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php(717): WP->query_posts() #1 */public_html/wp-includes/functions.php(960): WP->main('') #2 */public_html/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp() #3 */public_html/index.php(17): require('/www/webvol20/z...') #4 {main} thrown in */public_html/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 601

Code from /wp-includes/class-wp.php, lines 598-602:

```
$GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query'];
```

Code from /wp-includes/class-wp.php, lines 598-602:

```
public function query_posts() {
        global $wp_query;
        $this->build_query_string();
        $wp_query->query( $this->query_vars );
```

Can anyone help with the code changes that I need to make? Please provide a "for dummies" style explanation :)

Already went through all web available solutions, but nothing worked. But to be honest, I wasn't able to completely understand some of them.